# How to do lists comprehension (compact way to transform a list into another list) in c#?

Tags: c#, list-comprehension

In my code I frequently have the sequences like:

```
List<type1> list1 = ...;
List<type2> list2 = new List<type2>();
foreach(type1 l1 in list1)
{
    list2.Add(myTransformFunc(l1));
}
```

In Python, I can write it as

```
list2 = [myTransformFunc(l1) for l1 in list1]
```

Is there a compact way to write it in C#?

Comment: Your python example is not really a transform, but a list comprehension. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension

Comment: Note that Eric Lippert suggests using foreach in this case. I'm a big fan of list comprehensions, but after reading his post on this (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) I was convinced.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
var newList = list.Select(x => YourTransformFunc(x)).ToList();
```

Or:

```
var newList = list.Select(YourTransformFunc).ToList();
```

Func signature should be:

```
type2 YourTransformFunc(type1 value)
{
}
```

**Edit:**

Extension methods `Select` and `ToList` are in `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: is there a special name/module for `x => YourTransformFunc(x)` type of expression?

Comment: @YuliaV Yes, it's called lambda expressions. Read about delegates first and then about [lambda expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: lambda are available since .Net 3.5

Comment: @YuliaV Since you are familiar with python think of `x => expression(x)` as it was `lambda x: expression(x)`. The `=>` was probably choosen to remind the fact that the lambda expression "maps" a variable to a value.

Comment: @LuisFilipe Lambda Expressions are avaliable since .C# 3.0, you can even use them in .C# 2.0 when coding on C# 3.0 and compiling in C# 2.0.
Lambdas are not a .NET feature.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih: thanks for the enlightenment. Indeed they are a compiler feature; also i usually forget there was a 3.0. I guess you wanted to say coding on c#3.0 and targeting framework 2.0; never tried it though

Comment: It might be worth explaining the purpose of the ToList() as it may not be necessary to enumerate it straight away depending on what you really want to do with the IEnumerable

Answer (score 7):

You are thinking about this:

```
list1.ForEach(x=> list2.Add(myTransformFunc(x)));
```